# Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quickstart for service accounts returning blank page

Tags: php, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Looking to get an understanding of how I keep returning a blank page (no visible errors) when trying to access the Google Data API.

I've followed all of the instructions on this page (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) and would have expected to have seen the sample outputs the number of sessions for the last seven days for the given view. This is not happening.

```php
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);


/**
 * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 *
 * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 */
function initializeAnalytics()
{

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  return $analytics;
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "294613298";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled, so that any uncaught exceptions or similar, would not get just swallowed silently?

Comment: Thanks @CBroe - I added the below code to the file for the error reporting, but still with no luck.
`// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: You might simply not be getting any output, because it did not correctly fetch any data to loop over in the first place. Replace `printResults($response);` with  `var_dump($response);`, and see if that gets you anything that is not empty, false or null.

Comment: Looks like it returned a full page protected items?
`object(Google\Service\AnalyticsReporting\GetReportsResponse)#63 (10) { ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } ["collection_key":protected]=> string(7) "reports" ["queryCost"]=> NULL`

I can't make any sense out of it

Comment: It has `array(0)` in multiple places there, so to me this looks as if it did not actually fetch _any_ records ...? Which would also explain why your attempt to loop over any in `printResults` would not create any output then. `$rows = $report->getData()->getRows();` - checking what `count($rows)` gives after that line, should help confirm.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for the help. I’ll dig a bit deeper and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It appears due to UA View ID's being deprecated this will return NULL results, and should now utilise the Data API instead.